# How can I serialize hasMany relations with ember-data > beta15?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

Until ember-beta 14, everything was going fine.
I have `goal` and `account` models.

goal `hasMany('account')`, but account does not have or belongs to goals (not on ember, there are no reason on my app.

With a custom serializer, I had all working fine:

```
//serializers/goal.js

    import DS from 'ember-data';

    export default DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
      attrs: {
        account: { serialize: 'ids' }
      }
    });
```

my `post` request had all I need:

```
...
  account_ids: [1, 2, 3]
...
```

now I just have `account_ids: []`.
Ember nows about my serializer, otherwise I would just have `accounts`, not `account_ids` on the request.

I tried all possible combinations from [docs](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.html), with and without `{async: true}`, etc, nothing works.

What am I'm doing wrong?

I feel that it has something to do with the new `snapshots` api, but couldn't find any clue about how to work with it.

Thanks!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I had the same problem, but finally works with this:

Models/foo.js:

```
var foo = DS.Model.extend({
...,
...,
...,
bars: DS.hasMany('bar', {async: true})
});
export default foo;
```

Models/bar.js:

```
var bar = DS.Model.extend({
...,
Foos: DS.hasMany('foo', {async: true})
});

export default bar;
```

Serializer/foo.js:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin,{
  attrs: {  
    Bars: {
     embedded: 'always'
    }
  }
});
```

Serializer/bar.js:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin,{
  attrs: {    
    Foos: {
          embedded: 'always'
        }
   }
});
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: It is bad practice to both marking a relationship as embedded and using async. See http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.html.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help Angel VB.

But I came out with another solution, that seems to be the root of the problem.

Until `ember-data beta.14` you need to bind the `select` to `value.content`.
Ant it was working for both `single` and `multiple` select.

```
{{view 'select'
content=myDropdownContent
value=model.myProperty.content
}}

{{view 'select'
content=myDropdownContent
value=model.myProperty.content
multiple='multiple'
}}
```

From `beta-15` on, if you bind to `content` it seems to work, on `Ember Inspector` you see your data changing, but **it´s not serialized**.

The solution is very  easy, just have to follow Ember docs...

```
{{view 'select'
content=myDropdownContent
value=model.myProperty
}}

{{view 'select'
content=myDropdownContent
selection=model.myProperty
multiple='multiple'
}}
```

and now, with the same serializer, it work! It´s all serialized for backend.